# List currently logged in users in BlazeDS

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds

I really need some expert help here!. Does anybody knows of a way of getting the list of the users currently connected to a BlazeDS server? Is there any built-in mechanism of knowing this? or do I have to implement some kind of server side logic every time a user access my Flex application and store all logged in users details somewhere and retrieve them later?

Comment: Tomcat only knows about sessions. Your application should know about users. What is a "user" in the context of your question?

Comment: Hi @splash, a user is someone who starts executing the SWF (Flex application) embedded into the given jsp page rendered by a Spring MVC controller. This user will be automatically recognized by the security framework (spring security) because he/she would have logged in before using the regular login mechanism of the Spring MVC app (an HTML form)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nearest thing I can think of, using BlazeDS, is to obtain a list of clients currently subscribed to a destination, but this won't solve the problem IMO.

First of all, you need to define a destination and make sure that all clients will actually subscribe to it (see BlazeDS documentation for this). Then, on the server, you can then get a reference to the message service

```
MessageService messageService;

messageService = (MessageService) messageBroker.getService("message-service");
```

and ask for all subscribers with the getSubscribersIds method on the MessageService instance, specifying the name of your destination. This will only returns a number of identifiers, internally generated by BlazeDS (they are also available on the client side of the connection).

To resolve the same problem, I used this approach in combination to a custom server-side logic to store logged-in users (explicitly invoked login/logout methods). Regularly looking at the subscribers can help to clean this store, because in my experience there's no way to be sure that a "logout" method will always successfully called, expecially from Flex client running in the browser, while BlazeDS will automatically take care of cleanup of the subscribers.

I don't like very much this approach, probably someone came up with a better solution..

Comment: Hi @Cosma, thanks for your useful answer. Your solution seems ok to me, I just have to keep the server side "users store" in sync maybe listening for login/logouts as you said. I guess I could create a destination whose sole purpose is to serve as an entry point for all my users. Something like that should work, anyway I'll keep searching for any other possible solution. Thanks!

Comment: @leo, One thing to remember is that BlazeDS is not there for application logic, it's only purpose is as a data transfer layer and nothing else.  All other logic should be implemented yourself.

Comment: @J_A_X, yep you're right, by the way, do you know if a custom adapter is instantiated only once? I'm planning on creating a custom adapter and put there the logic to implement the "current users" store to know who is currently connected to BlazeDS but I don't know if this is the proper extension point to do that or if there is another point in the architechture where I can plug any custom class and make that work

Comment: @leo, I believe it's instantiated only once (unless otherwise specified), but don't quote me on that.  I'm more front end than back :)